# what the bars in keras training show?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, training-data

I am using keras and part of my network and parameters are as follows:

```
   parser.add_argument("--batch_size", default=396, type=int,
            help="batch size")
    parser.add_argument("--n_epochs", default=10, type=int,
            help="number of epoch")
    parser.add_argument("--epoch_steps", default=10, type=int,
            help="number of epoch step")
    parser.add_argument("--val_steps", default=4, type=int,
            help="number of valdation step")
    parser.add_argument("--n_labels", default=2, type=int,
            help="Number of label")
    parser.add_argument("--input_shape", default=(224, 224, 3),
            help="Input images shape")
    parser.add_argument("--kernel", default=3, type=int,
            help="Kernel size")
    parser.add_argument("--pool_size", default=(2, 2),
            help="pooling and unpooling size")
    parser.add_argument("--output_mode", default="softmax", type=str,
            help="output activation")
    parser.add_argument("--loss", default="categorical_crossentropy", type=str,
            help="loss function")
    parser.add_argument("--optimizer", default="adadelta", type=str,
            help="oprimizer")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    return args


def main(args):
    # set the necessary list
    train_list = pd.read_csv(args.train_list, header=None)
    val_list = pd.read_csv(args.val_list, header=None)
train_gen = data_gen_small(trainimg_dir, trainmsk_dir,
        train_list, args.batch_size,
        [args.input_shape[0], args.input_shape[1]], args.n_labels)
#print(train_gen, "train_gen is:")
val_gen = data_gen_small(valimg_dir, valmsk_dir,
        val_list, args.batch_size,
        [args.input_shape[0], args.input_shape[1]], args.n_labels)

model = segnet(args.input_shape, args.n_labels,
        args.kernel, args.pool_size, args.output_mode)
print(model.summary())

model.compile(loss=args.loss,
        optimizer=args.optimizer, metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit_generator(train_gen, steps_per_epoch=args.epoch_steps,
        epochs=args.n_epochs, validation_data=val_gen,
        validation_steps=args.val_steps, verbose=1)
```

I get 10 results (the number of epochs) as follows but I do not understand why I have 10 bars for each epoch? Are the accuracy and loss that is reported in each of the bars show the accuracy and loss over each batch? Are they only for one batch or previous batches are also considered in them?

```
Epoch 10/10
1/10 [==>...........................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.4046 - acc: 0.8266
 2/10 [=====>........................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.3336 - acc: 0.8715
 3/10 [========>.....................] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.3083 - acc: 0.8855
    4/10 [===========>..................] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.2820 - acc: 0.9010
     5/10 [==============>...............] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.2680 - acc: 0.9119
     6/10 [=================>............] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.4112 - acc: 0.8442
     7/10 [====================>.........] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.4040 - acc: 0.8446
     8/10 [=======================>......] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3811 - acc: 0.8597
     9/10 [==========================>...] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3623 - acc: 0.8708
10/10 [==============================] - 4s 398ms/step - loss: 0.3495 - acc: 0.8766 - val_loss: 0.5148 - val_acc: 0.7703
```

PS: the number of my training data is 659 and validation data is 329.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it shows cumulative results. You can change the verbose parameter to 2, that will stop showing multiple lines and you'll get one line for each epoch, or 0 which doesn't show results.